# mootools stop event bubbling when using Event.Delegation (:relay)

Tags: javascript, mootools, event-bubbling, mootools-events

I am adding events to links that are loaded via ajax. Here is a simplified example of the html:

```
<div class="ajax-content">
  <div class="parent">
    <a href="#" class="event-link">Click here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

All content within ".ajax-content" is loaded via ajax. I don't want the click event for ".event-link" to bubble up to ".parent". If it was not loaded via ajax I could do this:

```
$$('.event-link').addEvent('click', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  //do stuff
});
```

However, I can't figure out how to accomplish the same behavior with (click:relay). This is what I am trying:

```
$$('.ajax-content').addEvent('click:relay(.event-link)', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  //do stuff
});
```

How do I prevent the click event from firing on '.parent'? (I also tried other syntax - `event.stop()` and returning false, but they had the same results.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to prevent a delegated click event from firing on div.parent. This can be accomplished in my particular situation by adding a check on the event target in the div.parent event:

```
$$('.ajax-content').addEvent('click:relay(.event-link)', function(event){
  console.log("hi");
  event.preventDefault();
  //do stuff
});

$$('.ajax-content').addEvent('click:relay(.parent)', function(event) {
  if (event.target.match('a')) return false;
  console.log("parent");
});
```

Thanks to Dimitar for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 5):

consider your DOM order and order of event propagation from the top of the DOM tree down:

```
<div class="ajax-content">
  <div class="parent">
    <a href="#" class="event-link">Click here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

you attach the event to `div.ajax-content` (the delegator). which means, by the time that it hits it, it ALREADY needs to have bubbled through `a.event-link`, then `div.parent` and then finally down to `div.ajax-content`. there is no point in stopping it then, div.parent will come first anyway:

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/ChrCq/

here's what happens when you stop the event from the .parent before it reaches the delegator:

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/ChrCq/1/

delegation is not w/o it's downsides, i am afraid :)

you may want to also read this recent question / answer that went into some more caveats of delegated events and how they differ from normal events, how to work around the difficulties by alternating delegators. [Make (possibly dynamically loaded) element clickable via JavaScript, but give precedence to links contained within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759861/make-possibly-dynamically-loaded-element-clickable-via-javascript-but-give-pr/7761203#7761203) - I am still hoping the event delegation in mootools may change somewhat but I just don't see how it will help things in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply! This problem came up while porting this over from jQuery, which can do this using .live() - I was afraid that there would be a fundamental difference as you have outlined.

Comment: yes, this funamental difference came up on IRC last week, oddly enough - you can raise it shortly in the mootools office hour on #mootools (freenode.net) where all the mootools devs are available to answer questions and help - just make a test case with the mootools ver and the jquery ver that demonstrate the different behaviour. though I cannot think how it would work, there are some clever framework ppl that probably can :)

Comment: Just ran into this one head-first - thanks for clearing it up @DimitarChristoff